# Jupyter wont launch from Anaconda3 on Windows10

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I've recently installed Anaconda3 32bit version on Windows 10 but Jupyter won't launch.

- I've updated anaconda using conda and everything looked ok with all packages including Jupyter downloading.
- I've added the path to environmental variables.
- I've tried to run jupyter notebook from `cmd` prompt but still get the same error message.

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Edward\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'; 'notebook' is not a package
```

Comment: Have you tried launch it from the anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 1):

If jupyter is installed on your system you can also use cmd to open i as:

```
jupyter notebook
```

If not then u can use pip to install jupyter:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

or

```
pip install notebook
```

Then you can use cmd to open.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not download the latest version of Python.
Try downloading Python 3.9 first and see.

You can also download jupyter notebook from your OS terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I have tried these ideas. The root of the problem (pun not intended!) is in the path definitions I think. I have tried adding path definitions. But things that used to work fine like running pip from the C:\ prompt no longer do. So I have given up on Anaconda and now use Visual Studio Code for everything, including running a Jupyter Notebook.

Don't know why the system path definition doesn't work.  If I go to the directory containing pip it runs ok.

Many Thanks